# Accessing Service using Istio fails with 503 when under load

Tags: istio

I am load testing my service (using jMeter).  The service works just fine when accessed normally (ie via Swagger).

But when I load test it, it will start giving me 503 responses say "Service Unavailable".

But when I load test using IIS, I don't get that error.  I have tried adding a ton more pods (35), but the issue still happens.

While I would love a direct answer, I know that is unlikely.  What I am looking for is a way to debug this.  How can I get more than "Service Unavailable"?

I need some logs from Istio to see why it is doing this.  Is it really just too much for it?  Do I need to have 100 pods?  Without logs I cannot know.

FYI: My load test has 100 threads that continually call my service for 200 seconds.  My service takes the call and directly puts a message on a RabbitMQ server, and then returns.

How can I get more debug information out of Istio?